# Creating a steady rhythm for music-based game in XNA

Tags: xna, music, windows-phone-8

I'm looking to develop a game for Windows Phone which involves the user building notes into a sequencer while playing a puzzle game.

While my implementation is very *close* to being on-beat there is an occasional pause between beats, which makes the whole thing sound sloppy. I'm not sure how to get around this using XNA's infrastructure.

Currently I'm running this code in the Update method of my GameBoard:

```
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    onBeat = IsOnBeat(gameTime);
    [...]
    if (onBeat)
        BeatUpdate();
}

private bool IsOnBeat(GameTime gameTime)
{
    beatTime += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
    if (Math.Abs(beatTime - beatLength) < 0.0166666)
    {
        beatTime -= beatLength;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private void BeatUpdate()
{
    cursor.BeatUpdate();
    board.CursorPass((int)cursor.CursorPosition % Board.GRID_WIDTH);
}
```

Update checks to see if the time is on beat. If so, it calls the BeatUpdate method which moves the cursor over the board (sequencer). The cursor reports its X position to the board, which then plays any notes that are in that position on the sequencer. Notes are SoundEffectInstances, pre-loaded and ready to play. TargetElapsedTime is set to 166666, or 60FPS target.

Obviously totaling up the time and then subtracting isn't the most accurate or stable way to go. This current system is just horribly unstable. Beats lag and fire too early and it's obvious. I thought about perhaps some sort of threaded solution but I'm not familiar enough with multithreading to figure out how that would work. How could I fix this?

Comment: What's `TargetElapsedTime` meant to store? 166,666 isn't a number with any immediately obvious significance, except that it's 1/6th of a second in microseconds, or something. 1/60th of a second is **16.66** milliseconds or **16,667** microseconds.

Comment: Sorry, it creates a TimeSpan from ticks. I only remembered that I changed the default value (333333, for 30fps) to 166666. The set itself is a TimeSpan, created with TimeSpan.FromTicks(). I think the refresh rate might be a red herring though.

Comment: How are you getting the number of ticks? The preferred method is using QueryPeformanceCounter and QueryPerformanceFrequency, as far as I know. The Systems.Diagnostics.StopWatch class should be making use of those

Comment: When you make an XNA Game project, it fills it in as a magic number for you in Game1.cs.

Comment: @A-Type hm, the accuracy of that could be worth testing. In the mean time though maybe try this instead: Create an instance of System.Diagnostrics.StopWatch, `Restart()` it when `IsOnBeat(yourStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds)`  is true, and `bool IsOnBeat(long long time)` should return true `if (time >= targetInterval)`, where targetInterval would be the time between one sound starting and the next one starting in thousandths of a second

Comment: @melak47: so basically, replace GameTime's time tracking with StopWatch? That would be a good test of whether GameTime is accurate enough to do this kind of thing. I'll test that when I'm off work. Also, in case I never answered your question sufficiently, the variable TargetElapsedTime is meant to define the timespan between frames which XNA attempts to maintain (it's a fixed-timespan structure).

Comment: I would be tempted to sort the beat code into a seperate thread running it's own timer. Then set the timer to a fixed timestep of one 32nd of a bar (whatever that is for your current beat). That should help seperate it from performance issues with the rest of your game a bit. Provided the rest of the game is sequenced properly, the variable timestep (if your using one) for your game update should keep everything in sync, albeit with the odd visual sync issue relative to the sound.

Comment: I was thinking threads might be the answer, but I don't have much experience with them. For some reason I was under the impression that a thread would run at the same timestep as the main game, but now I realize that's not true. I'll investigate a bit. I imagine having a thread which only runs a timed loop to call one method would be a simple case and a good way to learn.